# Compile issue with Emscripten on Windows 7

Tags: emscripten

According to the [official documentation](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Using-Emscripten-on-Windows), I need to install Python 2.X, Node.js (0.7.3 or above), gcc 4.6, and clang 3.2. And indeed, they are all installed.

[image: Check, check, check, and check.]

*Edit*: Ok, I've updated this with a much simpler test case, which also fails.

**hello.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

**My attempt to compile using:**

[image]

For Google's sake, the error message is:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\jonathan\appdata\local\temp\emscripten_temp_7q2hkb\libcxx\libcxx.bc'

Why is this Emscripten-generated file not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got frustrated with this and ended up building a Ubuntu system which compiles things perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be using the 64-bit version? Or maybe you have to update your ~/.emscripten file ... or maybe Python is just doing weird things... or maybe .. who knows?

I also compiled emscripten on my native Linux with great results.  I think emscripten is really meant for native compilers -- not so much ported ones.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation on http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/building_emscripten_from_source_on_windows.html point 3 says you should

> Install Visual Studio 2010 (and possibly Microsoft Windows SDK for
>   Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4).

This is to ensure you have the necessary c compilers. There seems to be a common problem of the c compiler settings not being correct on Windows 64-bit.

Microsoft have a compiler download specially for Python 2.7 to address this:
Give that a try. If it doesn't work, there are some further steps you may need to take detailed at [pyusb 2.7 windows install error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304569/pyusb-2-7-windows-install-error/28500135#28500135)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference. Just seeing that you spread that link across the site: if you see duplicate questions, the way to go is to flag them for closure